# Ada/Eclipse Integration

Tags: eclipse, ada

Are there any freely available Ada plugins eclipse. Eclipse is my main IDE and I occasionally need to read and modify some Ada, having it all in the one IDE would be ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Eclipse, AdaCore distributes and maintains the GNATBench plug-in, though I've never personally used it. I *believe* it is not GNAT specific, so it may still be of value even if you're using a different compiler--but I could be wrong on that :-)

If you're using the GNAT Ada compilation system, you've got a fully Ada-aware IDE in their GNAT Programming Studio (GPS), which is what I've been using ever since it finally stabilized a few years ago. It's got the jump-to-definition, get references, specialized search, etc., capabilities that you'd expect.

These, as well as the rest of AdaCore's GPL Ada development environment and tools, are available from AdaCore's [Libre website](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/). Download page is [here](https://libre.adacore.com/libre/download/).

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out [Hibachi](http://www.eclipse.org/hibachi/):

> The goal of the Hibachi project is to create an Ada Integrated Development Environment (IDE) and tooling framework for the Eclipse platform.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is syntax highlighting, then maybe [EclipseColorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) will do the trick for you? It's a general-purpose extensible syntax highlighting engine that has definitions for Ada out of the box.

Comment: sounds good but It would be useful if it had advanced search functionality like type search/method search/references etc, jumping to definitions