# How do you do install ada into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ada

I've tried loads of sites to get GNATBench into my eclipse ide but can't seem to find the right link. If I could just download it through the help menu in the ide, that would be perfect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ada/Eclipse Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918722/ada-eclipse-integration)

Comment: What links have you tried? What host OS, eclipse and GNATBench versions?

Comment: download zip and install.. what's so hard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No joy on Eclipse Marketplace site.

Gnatbench 2.6 is there but no visible/manageable means of downloading it.

So go to:

http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations

Click on GNAT 2012 and GNATBench 2.6.0, ensuring that all constituent packages are also checked.
Click on "Sources" for both GNAT and GNATBench.
Then select all packages for each.

Select and check all other packages you're interested in by the same procedure.

Click on "Download Selected Files" and save the downloads folder on your desktop.
Move the downloads folder to your Administrator account, unzip, read the README file and first install GNAT 2012.
Then unzip the GNATBench 2.6, read the README and set about installing it from Eclipse :

Open Eclipse.
Help > Add > Local > Now browse to the folder where the unzipped GNATBench is.
Click OK.

This should return you to the Eclipse Install window and you'll see GNATBench installation units listed on the centre of this window.
Check the GNATBench option for AdaCore Plugins for Eclipse/CDT only. 
Leave the WindRiver interface unchecked -- unless you have WindRiver installed on your PC.
Complete the installation.

Comment: I have tried following these instructions, except I used the GNAT 2013 package. Still got GNATBench 2.6.0, as that is the latest version I could find. I am getting the following error:   Missing requirement: GNATbench Core 2.6.0.20111210 (com.adacore.gnatbench.core 2.6.0.20111210) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui.presentations.r21 3.1.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GNATbench Platform 2.6.0.20111210 (com.adacore.gnatbench.feature.group 2.6.0.20111210)
    To: com.adacore.gnatbench.core [2.6.0.20111210]

Answer (score 1):

Open Eclipse. Help > Add > Local > Now browse to the folder where the unzipped GNATBench is. Click OK.

Should be

Open Eclipse. Help > Add > Archive and browse folder where the zipped GNATBench is located. At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mac OS X, you might not find gnatbench available on the list, you will need to get it from x86 Windows (32 bits) and GNAT GPL from 2012 to 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few hints I used to finally resolve issues during installation of the GNATbench plugin for Ada under the Eclipse IDE for Windows 10 Professional 64-bit environment...

Look at Step 5 for installation instructions:

1. Only use the 32-bit versions of GNATbench (2014:
    https://www.adacore.com/download/more gnatbench-2.8.1-bin.zip)
    [Platform is x86 Windows (32-bit)]
2. Install the latest of both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the Oracle
   JDK 8
    https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. Only use a 32-bit version of Eclipse (Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a):
    https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/3a/eclipse-java-oxygen-3a-win32.zip)
4. Install the C/C++ Eclipse toolset
5. Follow installation instructions here:
    http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnatbench-src/html/gnatbench_ug/src/getting_started/getting_started.html#

This is what finally worked for me after many attempts to use the 64-bit version of Eclipse IDE (Version: 2018-09 (4.9))